# File upload from react to strapi, through an express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, file-upload, strapi

As a new learner of web development with React, Express and Strapi.  I want to upload a file from my React frontend to Strapi, but my frontend is communicating with the Express Server and the Express is communicate with Strapi Server.

I did manage to upload a file from react directly to Strapi, but when I try with my server in the middle, always get 400 error codes from Strapi and for me it is hard to figure out how to handle the `fromdata` in express.

Express:

```
/* File upload */
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.files.files
  console.log(data)
  try {
    await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${API_URL}/upload`,
      data,
    })
    res.send()
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error.response.status)
  }
})
```

React:

```
  handleSubmitFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('files', this.state.image)
    console.log(data)
    try {
      const addArticleRes = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/upload',
        data,
      })
      //SUCCESS
      if(addArticleRes.status === 200){ alert('Article created') }
      } catch(error){
          if(error.response.status === 404 || 400 ){
              alert('oops something went wrong')
          }
      }
  }
```

---

**EDIT**

I found a simple solution for my case: Usig pipes:

```
req.pipe(request(`${API_URL}/upload`)).pipe(res);
```

Comment: Hello, do you have any error logs?

Comment: I think that according to your code, your are posting to `${API_URL}//upload` can you try to remove the `/` in your express app config?